# Using checkboxes wix

Tags: wix

Hi I was trying to launch a custom action from a radio button but realized this cannot be done. Instead I created two checkboxes. I want them to have a shared property which I have done so as shown in my code but I would need for the user only to be able to select one at a time not both.

Heres my code:

```
    <Control Id="CheckBoxLock" Type="CheckBox"  Text="DiskID/NIC Adapter Address" Property="LOCKTYPE" X="50" Y="215" Width="200" Height="15" CheckBoxValue="0">
    </Control>

      <Control Id="CheckBoxLock2" Type="CheckBox"  Text="Hardware Key Serial Number" CheckBoxPropertyRef="LOCKTYPE" X="50" Y="230" Width="200" Height="15" CheckBoxValue="1">
       <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="OnLockOptionModified"><![CDATA[LOCKTYPE = "1"]]></Publish>
      </Control>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: From the user's experience point of view, using check boxes instead of radio buttons where one and only one can be selected is misleading. If the situation where both check boxes are unchecked is invalid, you should use radio buttons for selection.

Comment: @Alexeylvanov I know but I have a edit field that has to be updated from a custom action depended on the selection the user has made. Radio buttons would not allow for me to call a custom action. It's a pity windows installer does not allow this..:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long way around it but I created a work around that works:

```
    <Control Id="CheckBoxLock" Type="CheckBox"  Text="DiskID/NIC Adapter Address" Property="LOCKTYPESW" X="90" Y="215" Width="200" Height="15" CheckBoxValue="0">
      <Publish Property="LOCKTYPE" Value="[LOCKTYPESW]">1</Publish>
      <Publish Property="LOCKTYPEHW" Value="{}">1</Publish>
      <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="OnLockOptionModified"><![CDATA[LOCKTYPE = "0"]]></Publish>
    </Control>

      <Control Id="CheckBoxLock2" Type="CheckBox"  Text="Hardware Key Serial Number" Property="LOCKTYPEHW" X="90" Y="230" Width="200" Height="15" CheckBoxValue="1">
        <Publish Property="LOCKTYPE" Value="[LOCKTYPEHW]">1</Publish>
        <Publish Property="LOCKTYPESW" Value="{}">1</Publish>
        <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="OnLockOptionModified"><![CDATA[LOCKTYPE = "1"]]></Publish>
      </Control>
```

Then my custom action reads the `LOCKTYPE` property. Hope this helps someone else as it has taken me two hours figuring it out..:)